# Inaccessible value from control on embedded child form (Delphi, Firemonkey)

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, rad-studio

I am new to Firemonkey (using RadStudio 10.3.2), and I am trying to update a listbox control on an embedded child form.  However, when I try to access any of the properties of the listbox (ListBox1), they show up as "Inaccessible value."  I'm pretty sure that I am missing something very simple.  I appreciate any and all help!  Thank you!

I have made the following, simplified application, to illustrate my issue.

Project1 Application Initialization:

```
program Project1;

uses
  System.StartUpCopy,
  FMX.Forms,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1},
  Unit2 in 'Unit2.pas' {Form2};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Unit1.pas:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    procedure EmbedForm(AParent:TControl; AForm:TCustomForm);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

uses Unit2;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Embed Scenarios Form
  EmbedForm(Panel1, TForm2.Create(Self));
  Panel1.Visible := true;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  data_strings: array of string;
begin
  // Assign strings
  SetLength(data_strings, 2);
  data_strings[0] := 'Hello';
  data_strings[1] := 'World';
  // Load strings
  Form2.ListBox1.Items.Add(data_strings[0]);
  Form2.ListBox1.Items.Add(data_strings[1]);
end;

procedure TForm1.EmbedForm(AParent: TControl; AForm: TCustomForm);
begin
  while AForm.ChildrenCount>0 do
    AForm.Children[0].Parent:=AParent;
end;

end.
```

Unit2.pas:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Layouts,
  FMX.ListBox;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    ListBox1: TListBox;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

end.
```

The Form2.ListBox1 properties are inaccessable to the code on the main form--see the Button1Click event.  I have the parent form (Unit1) using the child form (Unit2).

I am at a loss as to why an enabled, visible component is inaccessible.  My modal forms never had this issue, so I think it has to do with the embedded child form.

Comment: Updated the code to show both the application initialization and fMain initialization.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. Please read [mre]. There is now a great number of irrelevant fields in the main form. But anyway, I managed to figure out how the previous code presumably was declared, but I can not reproduce the problem of yours. For example, you claimed `fScenarios.lb_Scenarios.Items.Add(data[i])` would not be accessible, but here it is accessible. I guess you don't have anything else (relevant to the problem) declared in the embedded form than the `lb_Scenarios: TListBox;` and that is in the published section, right?

Comment: @Tom - Correct.  I have now uploaded all the code, minus the controls which are irrelevant.  The main form recognizes fScenarios.lb_Scenarios.Items.Add, but when the code is running in debug, getting any of the fScenarios.lb_Scenarios properties results in an Inaccessable Value message.  I am wondering if there is some problem with how I have created the fScenario form and tied it to the panel (p_Scenarios) on the main form.

The code that fails is in the bScenarioClick event, and has been noted in the comments.

Comment: @Tom - I have uploaded new code to replicate my issue without any extraneous material.  This uses Unit1.pas, Unit2.pas, Button1 and Panel1 on Form1, and ListBox1 on Form2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is that you don't keep hold of a reference to the `TForm2` instance. Yet you attempt to use the global `Form2` variable later in the program.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Embed Scenarios Form
  EmbedForm(Panel1, TForm2.Create(Self)); 
  Panel1.Visible := true;
end;
```

`TForm2.Create(self)` returns a reference, which you pass to `EmbedForm()`
but then you loose it. 
Later in `Button1.Click` you call  `Form2.ListBox1.Items.Add(data_strings[0]);` but `Form2` is not assigned.

Change that to e.g.:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Embed Scenarios Form
  Form2 := TForm2.Create(Application); // Use `Form2` name declared in `Unit2`
  EmbedForm(Panel1, Form2);
  Panel1.Visible := true;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you, Tom!!!  That was the problem!  The sample is working perfectly now!

Comment: @Ric You are welcome. It was the simplified example that made it so much easier to spot the actual problem.

Answer (score -1):

You change "parent" but the "Owner" don't change

```
fmain.lb_Scenarios.Items.Add(data[i])
```

Comment: This produces an error stating, "TfMain does not contain a member named lb_Scenarios."  The listbox, lb_Scenarios, is on the child form (fScenarios).  The child form is embedded in the main form's (fMain) panel (p_Scenarios).  I hope this helps!  Thank you!